# Crystal Report Custom Paper Size?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need custom paper size in crystal reports like widt 5" and heght 7".
Is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, you setup your custom paper size on the printer and then Crystal pulls through the custom size when you set the printer within the Report at design time.