# asp.net Crystal Report Custom Paper Size?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

this is not a repost of this question [Crystal Report Custom Paper Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369186/crystal-report-custom-paper-size) :)

I need to show a custom size pdf via an asp.net web application so I cannot set the size on my printer since it resides on server.

Is there any way to set it? It's a very strange size (10 cm X 7.5 cm).

Any idea?

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Just to help people, for me this solution worked:

don't know why and how, but it's been enough to install the drivers on the server (not the printer) to make crystal work perfectly!

Stefano